# Selenium server v2 is unable to find element by xpath "//html"

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I don't understand how can this be. The error sometimes disappears but mostly it is actual. Selenium logs show the following:

```
Element not found with xpath, //html

Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//html"}
Command duration or timeout: 1.24 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.32.0', revision: '6c40c18', time: '2013-04-09 17:22:56'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'i386', os.version: '2.6.32-5-686', java.version: '1.7.0_11'
Session ID: cbfc080e-f4a9-4ec9-aa72-3a8adeb0e9b9
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, databaseEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, javascriptEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserName=firefox, browserConnectionEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=17.0}] [] []
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

**UPDATE**
I figured out that the problem is only actual for the following versions of the Selenium server:

```
selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar
selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar
```

selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar works fine with such XPath locators.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I have fixed these random errors, with two actions:

- I have added the tag **@insulated** on all my features. It closes the browser for each scenario. You can find most informations on the [Behat documentation](http://docs.behat.org/cookbook/behat_and_mink.html#defining-our-own-featurecontext).
- Then, I have added the option **--rerun** when I execute Behat because I have few random errors on few random scenarios. There are the options in the manual (./behat --help). Quickly, you can execute behat with this option like this : `bin/behat [@NamespaceMyBundle[/myFeature.feature]] --rerun .behat_rerun`. (bin/behat because I use behat in a Symfony2 project and I launch the command from top directory).
- A third option that I don't have implemented but is **recommended on Behat doc**, is to implement a spin() method which will scan and wait if an element is not available. The blog post is available [here](http://docs.behat.org/cookbook/using_spin_functions.html).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

1. Try changing the xpath to `/html`
2. Try changing the find method to `findElement(By.ByTagName("html"));`

Answer (score 0):

If the error is intermittent, is it possibly because webdriver is trying to find the element before the page has loaded? If you stick an appropriate wait in there, does it get rid of the error?

Comment: This, while it most likely uncovers the cause of the problem, should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Yes, using of explicit wait solves the problem. I thought waiting for the page load before doing any action should be default behavior of the Selenium driver... I was wrong.